# Message Passing Between Web Application and Chrome Extension - How to GET the message?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I am developing a chrome extension.

In my web application, there is a JavaScript embedded in a HTML page which tries to interact with my extension.

```js
let extId = "extension id";

var extPort = chrome.runtime.connect(extId);
extPort.postMessage({from: "WebServer", fn: "greeting"});
```

In my extension - background script, event listener is set to handle the message.

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
        if (message.from == "WebServer") {
            if (message.fn == "greeting") {
                console.log("Message from Web Server");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Besides, there is a function in the background script to use XHR to GET the HTML page. The function works fine.

Question: The message (which is shown in console log) can be got only when I visit the HTML page in browser but not when the page got by XHR. Why? (Sorry I am new to JavaScript and Chrome Extension)

Comment: XHR can't run scripts, it only gets the inert HTML response from the page URL. See [content.js in iframe from chrome-extension popup](//stackoverflow.com/a/39901725) which you can use the same way from the background script (the only difference is that you'll create iframe using document.createElement + appendChild).

Comment: Thanks so much. The issue is solved!